# spark sql query to delete with join conditions

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I'm trying to delete a table values checking with another table, like

```
DELETE Table1
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
WHERE t2.Col3 IN ('Two-Three','Two-Four')
```

It is not working as I get the above error `Exception` in thread "main":

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but
>   identifier DELETE found

Comment: I think I found the work around, but what I meant in the query was the Oracle example. I could do a select of it along with the required columns and I can do delete.

Comment: What is the work around you found, can you show by example ?

Comment: That was a long time back. I think I took the entire data into a dataframe and had the deleted data in another dataframe, then did an intersection to merge them and rewrite the whole data. I know it wasn't ideal and it could be overhead for the massive amount of data. But it worked for my case as it was not a zettabyte of data.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported. Spark enables delete with Hive and Hive supported syntax is:

```
DELETE FROM tablename [WHERE expression]
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Delete